# Can an element of a array know who is the owner of that array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, function, object

This probably seems a little bit strange but let me elaborate... I have an instance of an object (z is the instance  of Bla in this case), and it has a list of other objects (Bla2's), something like this:

```
Bla = function()
{
    this.array = [new Bla2(), new Bla2(), new Bla2()];
    this.x = 4;
}

Bla2 = function()
{
    this.y = MYOWNER.x; //in this case, z is the owner
}

z = new Bla();
```

Comment: How do you define "owner"? An array can be referenced by a variable held by any number of other objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default no elements don't know which array owns them.  Primarily because it's very easy for an element to be contained in multiple arrays.  Consider the following

```
var x = new Bla2();
var array1 = [x];
var array2 = [x];
```

In this case `x` is in 2 arrays hence having a single owner property will be inherently incorrect.

It is possible to manually create this relationship if a specific circumstance warrants it though.  Consider the following

```
this.array = [new Bla2(), new Bla2(), new Bla2()];
for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
  this.array[i].owner = this.array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was a very good explanation! I will accept your answer as soon as I can (7mins).

Comment: I think he was after the array item having a reference to the object owning the array, rather than a reference to the array.  If that's the case, a better option might be to pass the reference in the constructor arguments, e.g. `[ new Bla2(this), new Bla2(this), new Bla2(this) ]`.

Comment: Yeah that is true, jeez, I forgot what I needed... A good answer anyway.